# Add extra data to getList() in dataProvider

Tags: react-admin

For my react-admin project, aggregations are computed on server side (on ElasticSearch). The API sends back objects, total as well as aggregates, which will be useful for filtering.

The following code on the `getList()` function of the dataProvider runs with no error

```js
export const dataProvider= {
  getList: async (resource:string, params:any) => {
    // Build url with filters, pages etc...
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
    const { headers, json } = await httpClient(url);
    return ({
        data: json.objects,
        aggs: json.aggs, // <= here are the aggs I need for filtering
        total: json.total
    });
  },
  // other functions of the dataProvider ...
}
```

So this runs without error but my problem is: how can I retrieve the aggs data the API has returned?

The `useListContext()` hook, as documented [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useListContext.html), provides only `data` and `total`, not additional values sent back by `getList()`

The solutions I see so far are not satisfying.

**Solution 1**

Define an additional getter on the dataProvider, something like `getAggs()` but that will create an extra (and un-needed) call to the API

```js
export const dataProvider= {
  getAggs: async (resource:string, params:any) => {
      const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
      const { headers, json } = await httpClient(url);
      return ({
          data: json.aggs,
          total: json.total
      });
  },
  // other functions of the dataProvider ...
}
```

**Solution 2**

Use a `useStore()` in the dataProvider's`getList()` but that looks a bit dirty to me.

```js
export const dataProvider= {
  getList: async (resource:string, params:any) => {
    // Build url with filters, pages etc...
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
    const { headers, json } = await httpClient(url);
    // temporarily store aggs in local storage
    const [aggs] = useStore('aggs', json.aggs); 
    return ({
        data: json.objects,
        total: json.total
    });
  },
  // other functions of the dataProvider ...
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/9569) on the React Admin project to implement this feature.

Otherwise so far I found this working solution :

```js
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  return (
    <Admin
      dataProvider={dataProvider(dispatch)}
      ...
```

```js
const DataProvider = (dispatch: any = null) => ({
  getList: (resource: any, params: any = {}) => {
     ...
    return httpClient(url, options)
      .then(({ headers, json }: any) => {
        switch (resource) {
          case "transactions":
            if (dispatch) {
              dispatch(storeAdditionalInfo(json["additionalInfo"] ?? []));
            }
          default:
            return {
              data: json["rows"],
              total: json["count"],
            };
        }
    }
  },
  ...
})
```

By passing a `dispatch` to the provider you can then add the additional information to the store and retrieve them anywhere on the project.